# Any Api to check if password meets policy requirements?

Tags: passwords

Is there any API that could check is the new password is matching the Salesforce password policy or not?

We need to show the suggestion on the fly while the user is typing the password instead of showing the message after submitting.

[image: Password must include: ...]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query the following via Metadata API:

- For the Organization's default security, retrieve [`Settings`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_settings.htm) then look at [`SecuritySettings`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_securitysettings.htm) > `passwordPolicies` > `complexity`
- User's Profile's overridden security, retrieve [`ProfilePasswordPolicy`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profilepasswordpolicy.htm) which returns a record for each `Profile` that has a Password Policy differing from the Organization's default.  Then see `ProfilePasswordPolicy`'s `passwordComplexity` Field

See [financialforcedev/apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)'s Github repo for a great Apex Wrapper for the Metadata API.  Particularly, look at the subclasses of [MetadataService.cls](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls):

- Organization's default security:

  - `SecuritySettings`
  - `PasswordPolicies`
- User's Profile's overridden security:

  - `Profile`
  - There should be a subclass called `ProfilePasswordPolicy` which either extends `Metadata` (meaning you can call `readMetadata(...)` or `retrieve(...)`) or should be included when reading/retrieving `Profile`.  However, the subclass doesn't exist in [financialforcedev/apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi).  This could probably be added, and if you add this yourself, make sure to send a Pull Request!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can only access these settings via the metadata API, so you'd have to have administrative access to even see those settings, and then you'd need to parse the settings manually. This might be something that'd be a good [idea](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch).

Answer (score 0):

Depends how the login page is spawned.
The dynamic password complexity can be measured with Orgs password complexity requirements.The call needs to happen to wrapper api that takes the current password as input and internally does the check with Org password policy (based on settings retreived by metadata api).
This way the wrapper uses a different high level session internally not leaking any session info to parent login page and returning the current complexity assessment.